# One Time Pledge

Tags: pledges, civipledge

I am looking for a way to have one time pledge.  We want to collect pledges to made at our annual event but we do not want to run the cards till the day of the event. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? You can create a pledge that only has 1 installment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All well?

Not sure if this question is still relevant, but just in case - the only payment processor that currently allows you to set the charge date is authorize.net, and you would do so by setting up a recurring contribution from the back office for 1 installment to start on the date that you desire the card to be charged - I do not currently see how this can be done via front end registration.

Sorry not to be of more help :-(

Comment: I should have given you credit for this answer AGES ago. Hope you are doing well.

Comment: @SteveKessler Better late than never! Hope all is well with you too!